# Traefik. Split configuration and redirect to https

Tags: traefik

I'm new to Traefik and have following basic question. Traefik should proxy NGINX. My goal is to start the stack either with http (f.e. locally) or with https (production):  Therefore I've split the docker config in two yml files:

**docker-compose-https.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.permanent=true"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=my@email.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host('test.example.com')"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

This works so far. If I run `docker-compose up -d` with `-f docker-compose-ssl.yml` trafik jumps in for https and issues a cert. Without using it I can still start nginx over http. Unfortuantely what is not working is, as soon as Traefik is up it does not redirect http to https as my config should ask for. What do I oversee?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [RedirectScheme](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/redirectscheme/) for the redirection from http to https and the middleware to the router as mentioned in https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/overview/#configuration-example

So, your `docker-compose.yml` should look like this

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`test.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.nginx-redirectscheme.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.middlewares=nginx-redirectscheme"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secured.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secured.rule=Host(`test.example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secured.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secured.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

Comment: thanks @sai I see I've added the Redirect to the Traefik service but it should be added to nginx. But unfortunately, this does not change it. HTTP is not redirected to HTTPS. Do I maybe need to add a port to traefik or Nginx?

Comment: Hi @toni, I have edited the answer and can you try using that configuration once. If still it did not work, look at the traefik logs and see what is wrong.

Comment: Hi sai thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately I could not get this running with your solution. after several tries and errors I went back to defining the redirect in my traefik service which does it: https://gist.github.com/t-book/cb04653f03319862e80d13c171793ec7